# Auth Basic asks me for credential twice

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to

1. redirect my domain to https://www always for all domains, and then
2. ask for AuthBasic password if coming from a specific domain, such as dev.example.com
3. If I come from lb-example.com, for example, I want to go without Auth basic.

This is my rule:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /dev\.example\.com$/">
    AuthUserFile /usr/src/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected"
    Require user XXX
</If>
```

While entering dev.example.com it asks me for passwords twice. Do you know maybe why?

My infra looks like this:
dev.example.com -> lb-example.com -> Application

dev.example.com - Auth Basic needed
lb-example.com - Auth Basic not needed

Comment: Probably because you first redirect to the "www" variant of that name. Why ever you do that. You can check that yourself: open your browser's console, the network tab and check which exact request receives a header asking for authentication. Most like the first one without "www", the second one with. Keep in mind that those are completely separate hosts from the point of view the browser has.

Comment: You are right about debugging. Generally, I am wondering why because .htaccess first makes a redirect to www and then checks Auth Basic. So in that case this rule should be applied only for addresses with www.

Comment: Why should that be the case? There is no factor that magically _stops_ the application of directives in a configuration file just because _one_ module decides to apply a rule, here the redirection.